# When to use GenericServlet over HttpServlet?

Tags: java, servlets

I understand that the GenericServlet is protocol independent and an abstract class. So my questions is when someone would chose to use GenericServlet? Do you know of any specific example in mind that uses GenericServlet?

I have always correlated servlets with HTTP protocol and its responses and requests. I can not think of how a servlet can be useful in a protocol other than HTTP. It doesn't mean that it can not be. The option of being used in other protocol might have not been utilized in the past and there is no need for it anymore. Or it might be me that I don't have enough knowledge of it.

Comment: From the javadoc: `GenericServlet makes writing servlets easier. It provides simple versions of the lifecycle methods init and destroy and of the methods in the ServletConfig interface. GenericServlet also implements the log method, declared in the ServletContext interface.`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thanks. I understand that the simpler version of lifecycle methods are implemented. However, don't you have to handle the httprequest and httpresponse in your code then? Or GenericServlet will take care of that?

Comment: First, you can't have a `GenericServlet` object. The class is abstract. Second, the entry point of a `Servlet` is its `service()` method. You need to create an implementation class that implements that method. The `doXXX` methods of `HttpServlet` are called from the `HttpServlet`'s `service` method.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis This is where I don't understand the javadoc when it says makes writing servlets easier. You have to write your own service() method. While you have the doXXX paradigm if you use HttpServlet. How does that make it easier?

Comment: There is some boiler plate code you don't have to write if your class extends from `GenericServlet`. The `doXXX` paradigm, as you put it, is only relevant to HTTP and therefore only relevant to `HttpServlet` and its subclasses. If you want to create a `Servlet` for streaming music (or whatever) you wouldn't use GET, POST, etc. `GenericServlet` really acts like any generic `abstract` class, adding some very basic information you might want to reuse.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The short answer to your question is "Never. Practically speaking."

The long answer is that `GenericServlet` is an abstract (can't be instantiated) protocol-independent servlet, which is an endpoint accessible over a network like the web. `GenericServlet` provides some basic lifecycle management, but you have to extend it to make anything useful.

`HttpServlet` is an implementation of `GenericServlet` that handles many of the low-level details of the HTTP protocol like headers, chunking, cookies, and so on. As a practical matter, this is the only implementation anyone cares about.

I suppose it is theoretically possible one could extend `GenericServlet` to implement a different protocol like FTP or SMTP, but why bother?

Hope that helps.

Comment: What do you mean _why bother_ for FTP and SMTP?

Answer (score 1):

**GenericServlet doesn't implements all 10 HTTP protocol request (get post put delete head trace connect options etc.). so If you extend GenericServlet then all the request gonna invoke service() method.
as solution to this HttpServlet implements them so you can perform difference action according to the Request Received.**