# Why does Session Management is Not Possible by Using GenericServlet?

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, servlet-filters

In java servlet, whenever we create Servlet class by extending the **GenericServlet** class then session management is not possible.

So I am interested to know the same

Answer (score 2):

[HTTP Session](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_(computer_science)) is a HTTP specific thing. The generic Servlet has no idea of HTTP concepts, only the HTTPServlet does.

As to your next question: "When do you need GenericServlet?" the answer is [never](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254670/when-to-use-genericservlet-over-httpservlet).

Comment: GenericServlet is not protocol specific.

Comment: Hi @sanket no ! Generic Servlet is protocol independent and Http Session belong to HTTP so if we want to use session we have to use HTTP Servlet

Answer (score 0):

**There are no protocol-specific features in GenericServlet, which is an implementation of the basic, general purpose Servlet interface. Servlet-based Sessions are designed only for interactions using the HTTP protocol, which has two key features necessary for a Servlet Container to simulate continuous user Sessions: cookies and URL-based navigation, which supports URL-rewriting. The Servlet API therefore places the HttpSession interface in the javax.servlet.http package, and Session references are only available through classes in this package**

**So,GenericServlet class implements Servlet, ServletConfig and Serializable interfaces. It provides the implementation of all the methods of these interfaces except the service method.
GenericServlet class can handle any type of request so it is protocol-independent.
You may create a generic servlet by inheriting the GenericServlet class and providing the implementation of the service method.**